# What is the order of $\bar{2}$ in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{221}^\times$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, multiplicative-order

What is the order of $\bar{2}$ in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{221}^\times$?

I keep computing $2^0, 2^1,...$ until we get $1\ (\operatorname{mod} 221)$, but this will take forever! Is there an easier way to do this? A hint that was given is that $221= 13 \times 17$.

Comment: Cf. [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of $2$ mod $13$ is $\color{blue}{12}$ because $2^{12}\equiv1\bmod13$ by Fermat's little theorem,

but $2^6=64\equiv-1\not\equiv1$ and $2^4=16\equiv3\not\equiv1\bmod13$.

The order of $2 $ mod $17$ is $\color{blue}8$ because $2^4=16\equiv-1\bmod17$, so $2^8\equiv(-1)^2\equiv1\bmod17$.

The order of $2$ mod $221$ is the least common multiple of $\color{blue}{12}$ and $\color{blue}8$.

See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) about the Carmichael function.

Comment: $2^{24}\equiv1\bmod221$ because $(2^{12})^2\equiv1\bmod13$ and $(2^8)^3\equiv1\bmod17$, but $2^{12}\equiv1 \bmod221$ would imply $2^{12}\equiv1\bmod17$ (a contradiction) and $2^{8}\equiv1\bmod221$ would imply $2^{8}\equiv1\bmod13$ (a contradiction)

Comment: Thank you very much! So, the least common multiple of $12$ and $8$ is therefore $24$. So is this my answer? I also have a similar question in which I need to work out the order of $\bar{2}$ in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{161}^\times$, I know $7\times 23=161$ so the order of $2$ mod $7$ if $3$ but how can I work out the order of $2$ mod $23$?

Comment: Yes, the answer to this question is $24$.  $2^{11}\equiv1\bmod23$ by [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion), since $2\equiv5^2\bmod23$

Answer (score 0):

While the essence of the answer is the same as in that by JW Tanner, I would like to offer a solution in a more algebraic language:

By the Chinese remainder theorem, we know that
$$ \mathbb{Z}_{221}\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{13}\times \mathbb{Z}_{17}$$
by the isomorphism
$$ x+221\mathbb{Z}\mapsto (x+13\mathbb{Z},x+17\mathbb{Z})$$
The order of $x$ and its image have to be the same.

Both $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$ are fields, so their multiplicative groups are of order $12=2^2\cdot 3$ and $16=2^4$ respectively. Thus the order of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ has to be in $\{2,3,4,6,12\}$ (because its order must divide the order of the multiplicative group, this is Lagrange's theorem). Just trying these possibilities you see that its order is $12$. Similarly the order of $2$ in  $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$ is in $\{2,4,8,16\}$. Trying the first three possibilities gives that it's $8$.

Now if we are looking for the smallest integer $n>0$ such that
$$(x+13\mathbb{Z},x+17\mathbb{Z})^n=(x^n+13\mathbb{Z},x^n+17\mathbb{Z})=(1,1)$$
it becomes clear that it must be the least common multiple of $12$ and $8$, which is $24$.

Comment: And in the comments to JW Tanner's answer you mention $\mathbb{Z}_{161}$: The order of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{23}$ has to divide $22$. Doesn't leave you with a lot of possibilities.